# How can I remove backlog from indexer programmatically?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, indexer

I want to remove backlogs from the indexer when I check the indexer:status there I found many backlogs in the indexer.

[image: Magento 2 index programmatically]

I need to remove this problematically using corn job at every 2 minutes my cron job code is done now only thigs how can I remove these backlogs programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Those jobs in the backlogs are related to the MView from Magento 2, you can find them in your database as `_cl` tables. They are populated by triggers that you can see using `SHOW TRIGGERS` in your database.

To reset your logs and remove the items in the backlog you just need to reset your indexes status, remove missed cron jobs and remove the MView registers.

I use Magerun 2, you can do it via these commands:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias magerun2="./n98-magerun2.phar";
magerun2 db:query "DELETE from cron_schedule WHERE status='error' OR status='pending' OR status='missed'";
magerun2 index:reset;
```

To know the `_cl` tables that you have in your database you can run this command below.

```
magerun2 db:query "SHOW TABLES;" | grep _cl
```

Then you just need to clean up them.

```
TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_data_exporter_products_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_attribute_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_category_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_price_cl';
TRUNCATE 'cataloginventory_stock_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogsearch_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'customer_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'design_config_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_categories_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_thesaurus_cl';
TRUNCATE 'inventory_cl';
TRUNCATE 'salesrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_product_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_rule_product_cl';

UPDATE `mview_state` SET `version_id` = '0';
```

And finish it running the reindex.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento index:reindex;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be one of interfaces:

- \Magento\Framework\Mview\Processor::clearChangelog
- \Magento\Framework\Mview\ViewInterface::clearChangelog
- \Magento\Framework\Mview\View\ChangelogInterface::clear

It's called by Magento cron job `indexer_clean_all_changelogs` that clears processed Mview IDs:

- \Magento\Indexer\Cron\ClearChangelog::execute
- \Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor::clearChangelog
- $this->mviewProcessor->clearChangelog('indexer');

So I would:

1. Load latest version ID
2. Ask to clear change log passing current version ID