# Magento2 | Category links are incorrect in search autocomplete

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, autocomplete

My site is with Magento 2.4.4 multilingual and I use the ElasticSuite search module.

Every time I go to edit a category for each store view and try to search for that edited category in the elasticsuite search bar I find that the link to the category is wrong and comes back with 404 error.

So for example, if I search for the category "Writing" in the English store view and click on the link I get redirected to the 404 page.
From what I have read it seems to be a problem with Magento not being able to store the url path of the category properly each time it is changed.

I have already tried indexer:reset and indexer:reindex in all possible ways but that does not solve the problem.

**NOTE:** One thing I noticed is that in the index "catalogsearch_fulltext" there are "15371 IN BACKLOG". Can this mean anything?

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The indexer could be the issue here. You might have to clear the backlogs & have to do the indexing again.

You can follow the below link to clear the backlogs:

[https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347116/how-can-i-remove-backlog-from-indexer-programmatically#:~:text=To%20reset%20your%20logs%20and,x%20.%2Fn98%2Dmagerun2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347116/how-can-i-remove-backlog-from-indexer-programmatically#:%7E:text=To%20reset%20your%20logs%20and,x%20.%2Fn98%2Dmagerun2).

**Note:** After making any changes in Magento2, indexing is always required as the indexer syncs the data.